# How can I find my Postgresql username and password?

Tags: postgresql

I've forgotten my Postgres username and password and I need to set them as variables in the database.yml of a Rails app. How can I find these values?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better off resetting the password if you have access to the database:

http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-reset-password/